# What method is Microsoft Azure Backup using to encrypt data?

Tags: azure, encryption, cryptography

I'm filling in a security assessment form asking for the encryption method ("Are backups encrypted using AES-256 or higher?") used by the Azure backup agent software.

I can't find this piece of information on the Azure backup datasheet (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/backup/) or the Azure compliance pages (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/compliance/) or anywhere else.

I can find references to "...military-grade AES 256-bit encryption..." on "Storing Encrypted Data in Windows Azure" (http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2011/04/22/storing-encrypted-data-in-windows-azure/) that tells stories of customers using Azure, however, this is not a direct confirmation of the used encryption method by the current Azure Backup agent software.

Does anyone know or even better can any refer to documentation?

Comment: Extra info from "social msdn": Backup Encryption: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/330cb995-46bc-4be3-96d8-ae3b1268ca49/backup-encryption?forum=windowsazureonlinebackup

Comment: Ekstra info from "social msdn" "Encryption methods used by Azure online backups": https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b2b3ceeb-842a-4225-9ce5-05c09877d99f/encryption-methods-used-by-azure-online-backups?forum=windowsazureonlinebackup

Comment: Sounds like a rather dumb assessment. The mode of operation and how keys are managed is far more important than AES-128 vs AES-256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [`Azure Backup - FAQ`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-backup-faq/) page (Security Section). From this page:

> **Q1. Is the data sent to Azure encrypted?**
>   A1. Yes. Data is encrypted on
>   the on-premises server/client/SCDPM machine using AES256 and the data
>   is sent over a secure HTTPS link.